# Difference between dataType binary(1632) in SQL Server and dataType binary(255) in MYSQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to change my server from SQL Server to MYSQL Server. I just wondering what's the difference between the two binary(1632) in SQL and binary(255) in MYSQL. I wanted to know because it could affect the data that I am going to insert in the database.

binary(1632) = is the max value of binary in SQL Server

binary(255) = is the max value of binary in MYSQL

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Besides the obvious, that values may be truncated if you try to insert them in a smaller field? Besides, SQL Server's maximum binary field size is 8000

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, this has to do with the maximum size of the data the field is able to contain. If you really need the column be able to contain 1632 bytes of data, use the [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html) MySQL type instead.

Comment: so the equivalent of binary(1632) in sql is a blob(1632) in mysql?

Comment: I am not very familiar with SQL Server, but this is very likely to be -- although there is no such thing as `BLOB(n)` in MySQL, you cannot limit the size of a `BLOB` field, AFIK.

Comment: thanks, I take this as an option. I try to find more for other possible solution.